# Not all views are scrolling

Tags: android, android-layout, android-scrollview

I apologize, I'm still derping even after consulting SO solutions:
(1) [ScrollView causes the App to crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10053291/scrollview-causes-the-app-to-crash)
(2) [Adding scrollview crashes app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21520935/adding-scrollview-crashes-app)
(3) [App crashing after adding a ScrollView and ImageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19966201/app-crashing-after-adding-a-scrollview-and-imageview)
(4) [Add a ScrollView in Linear and Relative Layout in one XML file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15463913/add-a-scrollview-in-linear-and-relative-layout-in-one-xml-file)  --- etc.

Here's my situation:

> [--Subject--------------]
>
> [--Labels---------------]
>
> [--Participants--------]
>
> { mail message #1 }
>
> { mail message #2 }
>
> { mail message #3 }

**Current Behavior**: When I scroll, the {mail messages} move up, but [Subject-Labels-Participants] stays put as a stationary header.

**Desired Behavior**: When I scroll, the [Subject-Labels-Participants] and {messages} move as one elegant unit, scrolling out of view just like magical unicorns dancing off into the sunset.

**Code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

        <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="75dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/subject"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="13dp"
        android:text="Subject"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/labels_row"
        android:layout_below="@id/subject"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="4dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/labels_icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="17dp"
            android:src="@drawable/label" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/labels"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="44dp"
            android:text="Labels" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/participants_row"
        android:layout_below="@id/labels_row"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="4dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/participants_icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="13dp"
            android:src="@drawable/participants" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/participants"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="44dp"
            android:text="Participants" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/mails"
        android:layout_below="@id/participants_row"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

                </RelativeLayout>



</ScrollView>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="25dp"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/compose_reply"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/text_reply" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/reply_divider"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/compose_reply"
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="-1dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="-1dp"
            android:background="#CED0D1" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/voice_reply"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/reply_divider"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/voice_input" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/touch_reply"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/voice_reply"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I think we might need the complete xml because what you have looks like everything should scroll

Comment: wwhere's the ScrollView? Maybe show us the full actual layout?

Comment: Please put the original layout code. It's important to see the other attributes being set on the views like layout_width and layout_height.

Comment: @GreyBeardedGeek it's there now. It was missing a line break

Comment: What happens if you remove `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` from the `mails` layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want

> Desired Behavior: When I scroll, the [Subject-Labels-Participants] and {messages} move as one elegant unit, scrolling out of view just like magical unicorns dancing off into the sunset.

Then put everything into 1 RelativeView, within 1 ScrollView

e.g.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >


        More Views

        More Layouts

        More Views

        More Layouts


    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: thanks, it was actually a weird thing about the way we were populating the email into the list underneath, so we rewired the java instead, but your answer would totally work.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using separate layouts for each of the views? Did you try adding all the views to a single relative layout?